# Rudder only trajectory

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Assuming a vehicle with negligible body in fluid (plane, boat, hovercraft) and a deflected single aft control surface (rudder, not affected by propulsion) causing lift and drag in the fluid, what is the vehicle's motion?

Does it turn or drift?

I am trying to validate a simulation (expected turn, but it drifts) but can't think of an easy kitchen table type experiment.
The closest real situation might be an unpowered airplane using rudder for a <s>drift</s> *forward slip* landing. Flight sim or paper plane?

Comment: the vehicle is moving with respect to the fluid?

Comment: @user253751 yes, constant thrust, rudder causes drag and lift, limiting speed